# Use value from 1st party cookie as a data layer variable

Tags: google-tag-manager, cookie

I have a script on website (located in functions.php), generating some value which is stored in cookie. I would like to pass this value to a GTM data layer.

I've tried to import this value from from cookie as "1st party cookie" variable, and it works, but don't know how to pass it to a data layer.

Is there any way to use value from cookie deployed outside of GTM as a GTM data layer value?

Comment: Can you give more details on how you want to use it? In particular, do you need to combine the cookie value with information in the "true" datalayer variable?

Comment: 1st party cookie variable contains some string (taken from the cookie itself). I would like to use that string as a data layer variable value. Is that actually possible?

Comment: It is possible, but how you do it depends on whether the cookie contains the value of the only variable you need, or whether there are other variables as well - can you clarify?

Comment: Put a different way, why does this variable need to be a data layer variable specifically? What role does it need to play?